# Kivy/Python Math Application

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on a Python/Kivy application that is supposed to ask a user a series of math questions. My issue is that I don't know how to reset to another question, or get a list of questions. Here is a snippet of my main.py code:

```
def answers(self):
    """Ask the specified number of questions, and return the number of
    correct answers"""
    self.correct_answers = []
    self.incorrect_answers = []



    self.ids.questions_easy.text = "2 + 2"




def check_answer1(self):

    self.answers()






    self.answer1 = self.ids.answers.text

    score = 0

    if self.answer1 == "4":
        self.correct_answers.append(self.answer1)
        self.ids.result_easy.text = 'Correct, Great Job!'
        score += 1 
        self.ids.score_easy.text = str(score)

    else:
        self.incorrect_answers.append(self.answer1)
        self.ids.result_easy.text = 'Incorrect, Better Luck Next Time!'
        score -= 1
        self.ids.score_easy.text = '-1'
```

As you can see it asks the question what 2+2 is. That answer is then stored in the list "self.correct_answers". If it is wrong it is stored in the list "self.incorrect_answers". My problem is that I don't know how to make a series of 20 questions or so. I have been trying to think of ways like a "for" loop, or something along those lines, but am not sure how i'd go about doing that.

What complicates things is that my .kv file puts the question in a TextInput box, and the answer in another TextInput box, along with the result and score in two separate TextInput Boxes. That's a total of four boxes that are working together, so i'm not sure how to clear the question text input box and then generate a new question, while deleting the old question. For example, since 2+2 is my first question, I don't know how to change the TextInput box to ask what 3+3 is, or 9x9. 
Below is a snippet of my .kv code:

```
<Easy_Level>:
name: 'Easy_1'


GridLayout:
    rows: 6
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10




    Label:
        text: "Question"

    TextInput:
        id: questions_easy
        text: ""
        multiline: False
        readonly: True

    Label:
        text: 'Answer'

    TextInput:
        id: answers 
        text: ""
        multiline: False

    Label:
        text: 'Result'

    TextInput:
        id: result_easy
        text:""
        multiline: True
        readonly: True 

    Label: 
        text: 'Score'

    TextInput:
        text: ""
        id: score_easy
        multiline: True
        readonly: True 


    Button:
        id: get_question
        text: 'get question!'
        on_release: root.answers()
        size_hint: .1, .1

    Button:
        id: check_answer
        text:'check answer!'
        on_release: root.check_answer1()
        size_hint: .1, .1

    Button:
        id: back_button
        text: 'Back'
        on_press: app.root.current = 'select_difficulty'

    Button:
        text: 'Continue'
```

As you can see the "question_easy" text input box can ask a question, like, "What is 2+2", but I don't know how i'd delete that question, and then ask another question. I want to ask a total of 20-100 questions, but I can only seem to generate 1 question. I'm not sure if i'd run a for loop, and create a list of questions, or what. I've been stuck on this one for a couple of weeks, and am fairly new to programming. I hope my question was detailed enough, because I know that there is nothing more annoying than questions without detail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this will be much easier to solve if you build your Kivy UI from code instead of a KV file. Then you can make a "question widget" class that has a list of questions. You can add a method to this class that records the answer, then displays the next question in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedo code to make a Kivy question widget.

```
class Question(object):
    question_text = ""
    question_answer = ""
    question_widget = None

    def __init__(self, qtext):
        self.question_text = qtext

    def answer(self):
       # handle your answer

class QuestionDisplay(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, question_list, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionDisplay, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 6
        self.spacing = 10
        self.padding = 10

        self._ql = question_list  # keep a reference to your question list
        self.q_index = 0

        self.q_id = Label(text='Question')
        self.q_txt = TextInput(text='')

        self.add_widget(self.q_id)
        self.add_widget(self.q_txt)

        self.get_next_question()

    def get_next_question(self):
        # after your button saves the answer, call this to load next question
        self.q_index += 1  # display the next question in the list
        self.q_txt.text = self._ql[self.q_index].question_text
        self._ql[self.q_index].widget = self  # keep a reference to this widget in the question object; might be useful

my_questions = [Question(''), Question('2+2'), Question('3+3')]  # First question blank
my_q_widget = QuestionDisplay(my_questions)
```

This code is just an example of one way to do it. It doesn't handle your button clicks. It should give you an idea of how to organize your code to achieve this in and object oriented way.